# Какая это кодировка I.eaao(привет)

Tags: javascript, кодировка, unicode, cp1251, acrobat

Пишу скрипт на js для Acrobat. Подсмотрел в API возможность добавления своего(нового) пункта меню, на который потом вешается функция с нужными мне действиями. Всё отлично, но не поддерживаются кириллические символы в названии вновь созданным пунктов, с латиницей всё ок. Наглядно,
вот так работает:

```
app.addSubMenu({ cName: "Test", cParent: "Help", nPos: 0})
//app.addMenuItem({ cParent: "Test", cName: "Punkt_menu1",  nPos: 1, cExec: "Test()", cEnable: "event.rc = (event.target != null);"});
```

так не работает:

```
app.addSubMenu({ cName: "Тест", cParent: "Help", nPos: 0})
//app.addMenuItem({ cParent: "Тест", cName: "Пункт_меню1",  nPos: 1, cExec: "Test()", cEnable: "event.rc = (event.target != null);"});
```

Примечательно, что внутри самой функции есть возможность вызывать диалоговые окна, заголовки которых также не поддерживают кириллицу, но там выход мне подсказали, использовать Юникод кодировщик. Допустим слово Привет выглядит так - \u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442 в коде, а при работе скрипта отображается слово Привет. Но, к сожалению это не работает в названии пунктов меню.
Я пошёл от обратного написал слово Привет кириллицей и программа перекодировала его как I.eaao

[image: Так выглядит пункт меню]

Пробовал декодировать данное слово на многих онлайн-декодерах, но ничего не вышло.
Копаясь в установочных папках Акробата наткнулся на текстовые файлы с множеством кодировок, в каждой из них 3 столбца данных HEX, Unicode(HEX) и сопоставляемый им символ. В общем через HEX кодировку тоже не получилось, имя пункт выглядит просто как число.

Comment: В cp1252 (западноевропейская латиница) "привет" из cp1251 выглядит как ïðèâåò — похоже не ваш случай, если удалить диакритики.

Comment: Спасибо, я ранее видел этот вариант в декодерах, но выжать полезного ничего не смог. После вашего комментария возникла идея: перевёл слово Привет в Юникод, получилось - \u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442, вставил в код и Акробат отразил это как I.eaao. Тоже самое отражается если просто кириллицей задать имя пункта как Привет...хмм Затем взял СР1252(ïðèâåò) и перевёл в Юникод, получилось - \u00ef\u00f0\u00e8\u00e2\u00e5\u00f2, вставил это в код и опять - i.eaao

Comment: А не может быть так, что кодировка правильная, но шрифт не юникодный и неправильно отображает кодировку? Там есть возможность менять шрифт?

Comment: насколько я знаю, задать шрифт нельзя.

Answer (score 0):

```
X = "Привет" // "hello" in cyrillic
app.addSubMenu({ cUser: X, cName: X, cParent: "Help", nPos: 0})
app.addMenuItem({ cParent: X, cUser: X, cName:X, nPos: 2, cExec: "test()", cEnable: "event.rc = (event.target != null);"});
```

Оказывается, проблема поддержки кириллицы решалась параметров cUser!